# printf not printing to console

Tags: c, printf, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Using VS 2019 to create a C program to run in Windows Subsystem Linux (Ubuntu).
Compiling using `gcc starfire.c` as the original purpose of the program was for something else, but has devolved into this mismash.

```
void main() {
    printf("print this");
    return;
}
```

I've tried using `fflush(stdout)` and `setbuf(stdout, NULL)` and neither are working. Please help?

EDIT: I've also tried using `\n`, so it's not that, either. I'm also using `#include <stdio.h>` and it still just refuses to work properly.

Comment: Try this program: `#include <stdio.h>` `int main(void) { printf("print this\n"); }`

Comment: also it would be good to clarify your first two sentences: are you using WSL GCC as a custom build tool inside VS2019 ?

Comment: I installed WSL Ubuntu through the Microsoft store and am running that as a separate program (launched VS 2019 to code the program and then launched Ubuntu to use gcc to try and compile it). I used this with a previous .c program and had no issues.

Comment: Also, the program you gave me produced no output as well.

Comment: If you edited in VS2019, the file saved is likely UTF-16 with Byte Order Mark that gcc may not like. Open the *VS Developers Command Prompt*, change to the directory containing your file and (after adding the needed headers) compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O3 -o exenameyouwant nameoffile.c` (don't accept code until it compiles without warning) Then run `./exenameyouwant`.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin If the `.c` was generated with UTF-16, it is likely that linux `gcc` wouldn't even be able to compile it (syntax errors). Since OP has tried variants of the `printf` [and not reporting compiler errors], it seems more like a runtime issue

Comment: Yes, I thought I would be diplomatic in saying `"gcc may not like"`, rather than `"gcc will choke and puke on it`" `:)`

Comment: so VS2019 actually has nothing to do with the question, and you are using gcc under a WSL shell to build and run ?

Comment: I suppose. But I figured it would be better to include that information since I think it would inevitably be asked. As a sidenote, I should mention that I'm using VS2019 and not VS2019 Code, although I'm not sure how much of a difference that makes. Typically, I just use IntelliJ for my Java/Python programs (yes ik PyCharm exists but I don't think it has a CE).

Answer (score 1):

The x86 64 bit calling convention is *different* for windows and linux.

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions In particular, the "Microsoft x64 calling convention" and "System V AMD64 ABI" sections.

In Windows, the first *four* arguments are passed in registers. But, under linux, the first *six* arguments are passed in registers.

And, which register holds which argument is [again] different:

```
            arg0    arg1    arg2    arg3    arg4    arg5
Windows:    RCX     RDX     R8      R9
Linux:      RDI     RSI     RDX     RCX     R8      R9
```

Also, which registers must be saved by callee, which may be trashed, etc. are different.

Using `gcc` under Windows (`cygwin` or `mingw`) will use the MS convention.  Using `gcc` under WSL will use the ubuntu/linux SysV ABI (i.e. linux) convention.

So, you can't just do a cross-compile without some option to tell the compiler to use the correct calling convention. Also, there are probably issues with dynamic libraries (under MS they are `.dll`, but under linux, they are `.so`).

Also, windows uses the `PE` (portable executable) format [derived from SysV `COFF` format]. But, linux uses `ELF` object/binary executable format.

*Side note:* IIRC, MS just decided to support VS under linux [but that's very recently], so you might get some relief there.

But, IMO, I'd just use `gcc` et. al. under WSL/ubuntu/linux. And, *if* you really need an IDE, try Eclipse.

You could try to get VS to cross-build, but, IMO, the sign on the wall is: ***Abandon Hope All Ye Who Enter Here***

---

**UPDATE:**

*Caveat:* I posted the above based on the OP's original post [without the benefit of some of the top comments (re. how `gcc` was being used)]. But, the more I think about it, the less sense it all makes.

But, this begs the question: Are you using `WSL` or `WSL2`? They are implemented differently.

With `WSL`, MS just added an additional linux compatible syscall interface support to the win10 kernel. It could execute a limited number of programs. AFAIK, the programs still used the native `NTFS` file system. You aren't running a linux *kernel*, just executing some linux ABI compatible executables.

With `WSL2`, MS implemented a lightweight virtual machine [similar to `vmware` or `virtualbox`] that allows the full ubuntu/linux kernel to run. With this, you can install ubuntu by booting the VM from the "live" ubuntu installation `.iso` (straight from the ubuntu website). It then installs [pretty much] just like a native ubuntu install.

Because `WSL2` is a VM, you can install `fedora`, `suse`, `mint`, etc. in a similar manner.

Comment: That's a good point. I didn't think about the OP attempting to compile in windows and run in WSL (or vice versa). I haven't installed VS2019 yet, but I know they have made improvements on how they interface with WSL. Where before you could not edit in windows and have that file available in WSL without copying through `/mnt/c` to ensure the file was created with Linux file-permission information (otherwise the file would simply vanish in WSL). Hopefully the OP will provide clarification.

Comment: To my knowledge I'm using ```WSL``` and not ```WSL2```. Whatever's at the link [here](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9NBLGGH4MSV6) is what I downloaded.

What I ended up using was some online C compiler, since being able to run the code as a program (on my machine) wasn't terribly important. I just wanted to see the output for the code I was creating and making sure my coding logic was sound.